# WebLogic plugin within Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, weblogic

I am trying to start WebLogic within Eclipse

When it starts it complains like this.

Unable to load performance pack. Using Java I/O instead. Please ensure that wlntio.dll is in: 'C:\bea81\jdk142_04\bin;.;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\bea81\jdk142_04\jre\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0\bin\client;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0\bin;C:\sybase\JS-12_5\bin;C:\sybase\OCS-12_5\lib3p;C:\sybase\OCS-12_5\dll;C:\sybase\OCS-12_5\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Roxio Shared\9.0\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files\cvsnt;C:\Program Files\Executive Software\DiskeeperWorkstation\;'

> 

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that wlintio.dll is in the path. The location may vary depending on Weblogic version; in 9.2 it is in $BEA_HOME/server/native/win/32

Answer (score 1):

Add `$BEA_HOME/server/bin` to your `PATH`. This should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see native folder under $BEA_HOME/server

I can see wlintio.dll  under $BEA_HOME/server/bin

Comment: Probably due to differences in versions. I no longer have WLS 8.1 installed; I'm currently running 9.2. Either way, I think you should add the location to your classpath.

Comment: Actually re-reading the error message, I think that it is actually looking for it in your PATH rather than CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 0):

Being able to run WebLogic in the IDE is built in to IntelliJ.  It works right out of the box - no muss, no fuss.

Answer (score 0):

The performance pack is not necessary to run WebLogic server, so you can safely ignore this warning.